# How to preview HTML file in C#

Tags: c#, html, preview

How i can preview simple HTML file (C:\Users\Test\Desktop\test.txt) in C#?

Simple HTML Code;

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body
    {
        background:blue;
    }
</style>
<script>
    alert("test js");
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <buton>test<buton>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: C# doesn't have the ability to preview HTML. Open it in your web browser. You can launch the web browser from C#, but that's about it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'preview'?

Comment: By definition your file is not an HTML file, it's a text file with some HTML markup entered into it.

Comment: Indeed the file should also be renamed to test.html from test.txt

Comment: as "Preview" is exactly I mean, this HTML code preview on WebBrowser.

Comment: Double click the file, open in Chrome or IE or another browser.  Boom, you are previewing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to see what an HTML file will look like in a browser is to open it with a browser. C# is a software development language and can be used to write applications that will do what you want. If you're using Visual Studio there are extensions that will do what you're asking but I'd suggest simply opening it in a browser.

In Windows you can drag and drop the file, but you'll want to change the extension to "html" so the browser "knows" what to do with it. If you drop it in with a "txt" extension it'll just display the text.

BTW, you'll want to correct the spelling of "button" and close the tag with "/button" or it won't show up the way I think you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of browser components available for use with C#.

1. System.Window.Forms.WebBrowser allows for the viewing of HTML data.  It uses IE as it's backend, and inherits it's configuration from your Systems IE configuration.  Free.
2. ChromiumEmbeddedFramework aka CEFSharp.  3rd party component for hosting a Chrome instance inside your C# application.  Free, but comes with a setup overhead that SWF.WebBrowser doesn't.
3. Awesomeium is another Chrome based browser control for C#.  It is much easier to get going that CEFSharp, but it is only free if you are non-commercial.

I believe there have been some attempts to host Firefox, but have since died due to lack of interest.  Correct me if I'm wrong.